# Objective c title Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

The problem is that when I click the button the title gets double. For example I click the button the title become 2 from 1 then when I click the button the title become 4. and so on.
Can anyone know how to do this.

Code

```
- (IBAction)DoubleItButtonTapped:(id)sender { 
    NSString *dataToBePassed = @"To be Passed"; 
    ViewController2 *viewC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil]; 
    viewC2.dataPassedString = dataToBePassed; 
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC2 animated:YES]; 
    self.title = @"1"; 
}
```

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: Please show us your code. From your answer nothing is clear.

Comment: - (IBAction)DoubleItButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    NSString *dataToBePassed = @"To be Passed";
    ViewController2 *viewC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    
    
    viewC2.dataPassedString = dataToBePassed;

    
    
    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC2 animated:YES];
    self.title = @"1";
    
}

Comment: i just want when i tap the button the title get multiply by 2

Comment: what are you trying to implement? pass data to next view controller or do some action on button click ?

Comment: i just want to double the title whenever i click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to get title multiply, without navigate to other screen here is your code

```
- (IBAction)DoubleItButtonTapped:(id)sender {
        int count = [[[(UIButton *)sender titleLabel] text] intValue] ;
        if (count == 0) {
         count += 2;
        } else {
         count *= 2;
       }
        [sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
```

If you want also want to navigate to other screen you can add your navigation screen to the code

```
NSString *dataToBePassed = @"To be Passed"; 
ViewController2 *viewC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil]; 
viewC2.dataPassedString = dataToBePassed; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC2 animated:YES];
```

Note: In my project it works with any default string also but if you get any issue on click of button, please set the default title of button to '1' at start

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)DoubleItButtonTapped:(id)sender {
int titleNumber = [[[(UIButton *)sender titleLabel] text] intValue] ;
titleNumber = titleNumber*2;
[sender setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",titleNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

- (IBAction)DoubleItButtonTapped:(id)sender {

self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title intValue]*2];

ViewController2 *viewC2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

viewC2.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title intValue]*2];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC2 animated:YES];

}